# Terminal - lose useful keyboard shortcuts during SSH connection

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh

I'm encountering an annoying issue. When I'm connecting to a Linux VM through my terminal by ssh, I don't have tab completion, or I can't navigate through my past commands with the directional arrows.

Do you have any idea on how to fix the cumbersome problem? Is it linked with the configuration of my terminal? Here is the output of the `env` command:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/7m/9zh3pls10rd37f0bf1zgqtwm0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jILyAJx9OV/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=BB429A67-27F3-4A50-A891-DD5F15C2E2D9
USER=***
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=***
PWD=***
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=***
LOGNAME=***
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
GOPATH=***
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.7rCzuMNc2V/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab completion etc is configured in the shell, not in Terminal. So if you miss that functionality when logging in into a remote system you need to configure it in the shell you are running there.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Do you know to do it? And is this not disturb the shell configuration for other users that want to connect to this remote VM?

Comment: @BastianNanchen Well, configuring a shell on a Linux system is kind of off-topic here, but https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-enable-bash-auto-completion-in-centos-rhel/, https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-add-bash-completion-in-debian or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777017/how-to-enable-tab-completion-of-command-line-switches-in-bash (and the links therein) might help. Configurations can be done on a per-user basis, so if others use a different login for the same VM they won't notice your changes.